# Active Directory - get all users in multiple Ad Groups

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Is there a way to get all active users in multiple groups?

For example:

> Get all active users in "AdGroupA" OR "AdGroupB" OR "AdGroupC"

I have see post about single group but not multiple groups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to return the entire list of users in multiple groups?  That should be as easy as getting the users from the single group multiple times.

```
public IEnumerable<UserPrincipal> GetUsersFromGroups(string[] groupNames)
{
    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        foreach (var groupName in groupNames)
        {
            foreach (var userPrincipal in GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName)
                                               .GetMembers())
            {
                yield return userPrincipal;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is a method not using `AccountManagement`:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

public static IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> GetUsersFromGroups(string[] groupNames)
{
    if (groupNames.Length > 0)
    {
        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        string searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=Group)"; //filter for groups
        searchFilter += "(|"; //start a group of or parameters

        foreach (var group in groupNames)  // loop through the group names
        {
            searchFilter += string.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})",group); //add a parameter for each group in the list
        }

        searchFilter += "))"; //close off the filter string
        searcher.Filter = searchFilter; //add the filter to the searcher

        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member"); // load the members property for the group

        var searchResults = searcher.FindAll(); // perform the search

        foreach (SearchResult result in searchResults)
        {
            var directoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)result.GetDirectoryEntry(); // get the directory entry for the group
            PropertyValueCollection members = directoryEntry.Properties["member"]; // get the members collection

            foreach (string name in members)   // iterate over the members. This string will be the distinguished name
            {
                yield return new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}",name)); //return the directory entry. You may get the entry and return the display name or just return distinguished name.
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

In my environment I found this to be about 25% faster on average than using `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` for 1 group, but as the count of groups and users increased the `AccountManagement` method actually became faster. This only queries AD once while the first method queries once per group.

Comment: I had similar to this but it takes too long ( about 10 secs)

Comment: 3 Groups and i get about 500 users. not that much users, not sure why it is taking soo long.  I will give a try without using Accountmanagement

Comment: That is kinda a lot of users.  Is this something you're going to be accessing frequently where performance is a huge issue?  If so, I'd recommend creating a database to hold the information which you would be able to access very quickly.  Security groups aren't likely to change very often, so you could probably get by doing this and refreshing the table daily.

Comment: I know its too old. Just checking will `searcher.PageSize=1000;` make a difference in performance with your code?